Traceback (most recent call last) : Python
I wrote this code:
import pandas as pd
def solve(df):
print(df.loc[0:2, 'Total':'Payment'])

df = pd.read_csv('supermarket1.csv', sep=';')
solve(df)

An then i get this error :
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__tester__.python3", line 37, in <module>
    solve()
*your text*TypeError: solve() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'


Please post your real code. Your code and the error traceback do not match up.

Apart from the indentation issues in the first block, which I assume was a transcription error, there's no reason that code should produce that error. Please [edit] your question to include the actual relevant code that's causing this error.

Ok I´ve already got this right tnaks !

What did you get right? What was the actual error produced from your code?
